# Importing users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import

I am using  WordPress to build my website
and I want to import users into my website and I am using WP all import plugin for this job but it doesn't work , when I upload my csv file that includes the users,  it only imports the first user in the list and I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these plugins as an alternative. THese are in order of success rate and better functionality.

1. [Import and export users and customers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/)
2. [Import Export WordPress Users and WooCommerce Customers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/)
3. [User Import with meta](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users/)

I'd recommend the 1st one. It's so far the most simple and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If SSH is available you can try to use WP-CLI for this job:
[Import Users via WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/import-csv/)